# SFMC - engagement split tracking a specific link click sends everyone who clicked any link down the "Yes" path instead

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I've have encountered an unusual occurrence in how the engagement split tracking clicks acted for a specific journey. The engagement split was set up to track clicks on a specific link and to send users down the Yes Path if they clicked on that specific link. However, what happened is that the engagement split sent users down the Yes path if the clicked on any link inside the email, not just the selected one.

So all users who clicked anything in the email were sent down the yes path of the engagement split which was set up to track only clicks to the specific link.

Anyone had a similar experience? Buttons and links were generated in html if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your decision split and the journey path?